# MYSQL Error #1064 when trying to update a table using the sum from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-error-1064

I have been working on this problem for a few days now and have searched forum after forum. I have come up with the same answer for formatting this question but I continue to get the same issue. I hope that someone can help. I am getting an error #1064 on this code. I know it has to do with calling the student table I have been unable to fix the error.

```
UPDATE
  s 
SET
  tot_cred = u.real_cred 
FROM
  student s
  JOIN (
    SELECT ID, SUM( credits ) real_cred
    FROM takes t
    JOIN course c ON t.course_id = c.course_id
    WHERE grade <>  'F'
    AND grade IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY ID
  ) u ON s.ID = u.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using update with join syntax for `SQL Server`, here's for `MySQL`:

```
UPDATE  student s 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  ID,     SUM( credits ) real_cred
            FROM    takes t
                    INNER JOIN course c 
                        ON t.course_id = c.course_id
            WHERE   grade <>  'F' AND 
                    grade IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP   BY ID
        ) u ON s.ID = u.ID
SET     s. tot_cred = u.real_cred
```